# the amplitude of the sum of two vectors

Tags: summation, vectors, maxima-minima

$X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, $Y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ and $Z=aX+Y$, $a>0$.

If $a$ increases, would $\max(Z)-\min(Z)$ increase? i.e., is $\max(Z)-\min(Z)$ a non-decreasing function of $a$?

$X$ and $Y$ are real numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Since $Z$ is a function of $a$, what is $max(Z)$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are known vectors. It is $a$ who is the variant in $Z$.

Comment: Yes, and I asked what is $max(Z)$? Is it $$\max_a(Z) = Y + X \max_a (a)? $$ which is just $\infty$!

Comment: No. $max(Z)=max(a*x_1+y_1,a*x_2+y_2,...,a*x_n+y_n)$.  I am asking that if a changes, how would $max(a*x_1+y_1,a*x_2+y_2,...,a*x_n+y_n)-min(a*x_1+y_1,a*x_2+y_2,...,a*x_n+y_n)$ changes.

Comment: It will be increasing for $a$ large enough, but there's no reason for it to be increasing for small values of $a$.